# Dot Product from Two Vectors as Float?

Tags: java, vector

is there an existing function in java where i can get the dot product of two Vectors? Like:

```
float y = Math.cos(dot(V1, v2));
```

Where v1 and v2 are Three Dimensional Vectors (Vector3f)

Comment: What kind of `Vectors` are we talking about here?

Comment: What's the `Math.cos` for?

Comment: TO show that it should return a float. No need to down vote my question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a method in the `Vector3f` class called `dot(Vector3f)`:

http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.1/javax/vecmath/Vector3f.html#dot(javax.vecmath.Vector3f)

You can do:

```
float dotProduct = V1.dot(V2);
```

Where `V1` and `V2` are both instances of `Vector3f`.